# Retrieve all the attribute values from XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, value-of

I can't figure out how to access all the attributes in a tag from an XML document.

Let's say I have the following XML:

```
<names>
  <name firstname="Rocky" lastname="Balboa" divider=", "/>
  <name firstname="Ivan" lastname="Drago" divider=", "/>
</names>
```

I want the following output:
`Rocky Balboa, Ivan Drago,`

What I currently have is:

```
<xsl:for-each select="names/name">
   <xsl:value-of select="@firstname"/>
   <xsl:value-of select="@lastname"/>
   <xsl:value-of select="@divider"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

What I'm wondering is if it's possible to do this in just one value-of select instead of having to do three of them. So to clarify, I want to be able to output all the attributes in the tag with one single value-of select. Is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: You can use this XPath @* to get all attributes, e.g.:  <br/>       <xsl:template match="/*">
            <xsl:for-each select="@*">
               <xsl:value-of select="concat(name(), ': ', ., ' ')"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:template>

Comment: please consider the fromatting. Due to strange reasons formatting is not working on my end.

Comment: Alright I guess you could do that aswell. But I want to figure out how/if this is possible to do it in the way I have, but with just one value-of select.

Comment: That is what I mentioned. If you refer to above example @* use you will see it will require just one value-of select and you will be good. I hope this helps. I am re-posting my comment with better indentation and formatting below. Hoe that will help.

Comment: How would you like to handle blanks. This is not even reasonable in your current _solution_. (You are generation `RockyBalboa, IvanDrago, `.)

Comment: Why is it you have to use value-of. I think the solution would be to have a template for name (perhaps with a mode) and have than one line like: `<xsl:apply-templates  select="names/name" mode="print"/>`

Answer (score 7):

try the following:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
 <xsl:for-each select="names/name/@*">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat( ., ' ')"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Lolz - upvoting an answer about XSLT in 2019 - this works great tho!

Answer (score 2):

Because I'm not sure if the use of `xsl:value-of`is a hard requirement, perhaps something like the following could be what you are locking for.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="name" mode ="print" >
        <xsl:value-of select="@firstname"/>
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="@lastname"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="@divider"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates  select="names/name" mode="print"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You can use `<xsl:apply-templates select="names/name" mode="print"/>` 
 at any position you have considered about using a one line value-of  for all attributes.
The above template will generate the following output:

```
Rocky Balboa, Ivan Drago,
```

**Update crate output without using the attribute names:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="name" mode ="print" >
        <xsl:for-each select="@*" >
            <xsl:if test="not(position() = last() or position() = 1)">
                <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>

        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates  select="names/name" mode="print"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this XPath @* to get all attributes, e.g.:

```
<xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:for-each select="@*">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(name(), ': ', ., ' ')"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

This will let you use just one value-of select to get the output you want. It will take all attribute into consideration.

This should be a sufficient hint for you to figure out things. Let me know if you have any other question.

Comment: This has not much to do with the request. You are generating something like `firstname: Ivan lastname:...` (if any). But requested is: `Rocky Balboa, Ivan Drago,`

Answer (score 0):

If you can use XSLT 2.0, you can do something like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="text()"/>

    <xsl:template match="*[@*]">
        <xsl:value-of select="@*[not(name()='divider')]" separator=" "/>
        <xsl:value-of select="@divider"/>           
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This will output all attributes and you have no control over the order, so if you want to specify an order, you can either use a sequence:

```
<xsl:value-of select="(@firstname,@lastname)" separator=" "/>
```

or do an `xsl:apply-templates` with an `xsl:sort` to sort the attributes by `name()` (or whatever). Let me know if you'd like an example.

Comment: I must have explained myself wrong. I'm wondering if its possible to print out all the attributes, not but calling the names of the attributes. Something like value-of select "*" or along those lines.

Comment: @ErikÅstrand - That's what `<xsl:value-of select="@*[not(name()='divider')]" separator=" "/>` does except that it ignores the `divider` attribute. You could also do `<xsl:value-of select="@*" separator=" "/>`, but you wouldn't be guaranteed that `divider` would be the last output.

Answer (score 0):

The following works in XSLT 2.0:

```
<xsl:for-each select="names/name">
   <xsl:value-of select="@firstname, @lastname, @divider"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

and in 3.0 you can do:

```
<xsl:value-of select="names/name!(@firstname, @lastname, @divider)"/>
```

though you may need to make adjustments to get the whitespace the way you want it.

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the reply. I'm not acually wondering how to print out all the attributes in one line by calling the acual names of the attributes. I'm looking for a way to simply call all the attributes, regardless of the names. Something along these lines: value-of select = " * ". Something that can print all the attributes, but not by calling them individually.